# Backendless - Ambiguous reference error with Twitter login

Tags: android, twitter, backendless

I have found a curious behaviour in Backendless Twitter login, two of the available uses of the "loginWithTwitter" method are:

```
loginWithTwitter(
    Activity context,
    Map<String, String> twitterFieldsMapping,
    AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser> responder, 
    boolean stayLoggedIn
)
```

and

```
loginWithTwitter(
    Activity context,
    WebView webView,
    AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser> responder, 
    boolean stayLoggedIn
)
```

Of course it is our choice if we send "twitterFieldsMapping" and "webView" parameters, but if we use it in this way:

```
Backendless.UserService.loginWithTwitter(
    LoginActivity.this, 
    null, 
    loginCallback, 
    true
);
```

We will get an error because it is an ambiguous reference to loginWithTwitter method.

Error raised in Android Studio:

> Error:(69, 32) error: reference to loginWithTwitter is ambiguous, both
>   method
>   loginWithTwitter(Activity,WebView,AsyncCallback,boolean)
>   in UserService and method
>   loginWithTwitter(Activity,Map,AsyncCallback,boolean)
>   in UserService match

Am I missing some underlying behaviour here? Facebook and Google+ login methods work perfectly and they have 5 methods each, while Twitter has 8 methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, passing null would make the call ambiguous, therefore there is another signature which does not take neither WebView nor twitterFieldMappings (which is one of the extra methods in comparison to FB and Google):

```
public void loginWithTwitter( android.app.Activity context, AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser> responder, boolean stayLoggedIn )
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry, I didn't see it!! otherwise, is that ambiguous call an issue to be fixed?

Comment: And of course, does it have a reason to not do it in the same way as facebook or google+ ? (with just 5 methods).

Comment: No, that "issue" will not be fixed because a developer has full control over what method is called. The ambiguity can be easily resolved by invoking a proper method.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Don't you think that doing both 3 login methods work in the same way will be easy/understand for your users?

Comment: There are differences in login support between these vendors which justify extra methods.